# How to vertically center in yui-pure-css?

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I use purecss (purecss.io), which works fantastic so far, but I haven't managed to vertically center anything in their responsive grid.

I have a div (class="pure-u-1-3") with automatically has the height of it's parents element. I would like to vertically center a form (tried wrapping in a div too) inside this. I tried everything I found on StackOverflow and many other sources online. Unfortunately it seems that pure-css is destroying it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer to your question?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I managed to work it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.pure-g-valign-fix{display:block;}
```

Use class above to fix the vertical align issue with PureCSS in it's grids. Use CSS class alongside the `pure-g` class like so:

```
<div class="pure-g pure-g-valign-fix">
```

Doing this will bring back normal CSS behaviour for that row.